# How to hide parameters in url in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My Url Is like
https://www.Mydomainname.com/Service/subServices/2
I want it like
https://www.Mydomainname.com/Service/subServices
But i want to use this [2] as id how i hide this parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would have to do a post. Using get will always result in the parameters being appended.

Comment: because i am using hyperlink

Comment: Then unfortunately you'll be stuck with a parameter in some way.

Comment: so is that any way to redirect to another page without showing this parameter ?

Comment: Assuming you still want to show the data on that page? No. In order to show whatever item matches that ID with a get request and MVC it will need to be in the URL. A post would get around it only because the ID would be sent in the request body.